# NT Registry Handle Behaviour

Tags: c, windows, registry, driver, virtualization

I am doing an application virtualization project. So I hook applications in NT level and will direct the registry calls to my virtual registry. On running any application, if I go to File -> Open.. I have few registry calls like the below:

1. `ZwOpenKey(registry key path)` -> it produces the handle ex:(0x04e8)
2. `ZwQueryKey(0x4ea,...)`

Process Monitor says both open and query are performed on same key. I myself tested and confirmed that is the same key.

Also query key produced the right result for the querykey api.
This 2 byte difference is not for all open and query key cases.

How and why the application changes the handle from `0x4e8` to `0x4ea` before it invokes `querykey`?

I have also tested the invocation of `ZWDuplicateObject` between the open and querykey, however the duplicateobject api is not invoked.

Can anyone say how this handle changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lowest two bits of a handle aren't used by the kernel, and so applications are free to set them to other values and/or some APIs use these as additional flags, rather than having an extra parameter

```
0x4ea & 0xffc == 0x4e8 & 0xffc
```

Raymond Chen did [a series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/27/8898863.aspx) discussing possible uses for these bits:

> Kernel handles are always a multiple of four; the bottom two bits are available for applications to use. But why would an application need those bits anyway?

Comment: Damien, I am learning the links. Thank you very much for such a good direction. I will try to work out that for my case.. Between would you have any experience in handling the 2 bits.